# Building a voice assistant into a software

Tags: nlp, voice-recognition, amazon-lex

I am new to natural language processing. I am looking into embedding a voice assistant into a software that will help perform tasks (logging in, running a report etc.).

The software already uses AWS and I was thinking if amazon Lex (or any other service/tool) has the capabilities I am looking for.

Is there any ready to use platforms that I can test?

Answer (score 0):

If intent extraction is what you're looking for Try api.ai i have tested it and its straight forward. Let me know if need assistance . I have few examples in my github

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to embed the voice assistant in your app, try alan.app. They have a platform for contextual in-app voice assistance that can be deployed in days.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).